# How to get virtual expression in mysql?

Tags: mysql, data-virtualization

I have a table with a virtual field like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE `deleteme` (
    `number` int(11),
    `result` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`number` + 1) STORED
)
```

How to get the expression from virtual field `result`?

```
`number` + 1
```

I would like avoid using `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to search for the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could query metadata tables:

```
SELECT column_name, generation_expression
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'deleteme';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=52271b57460959fd5c79705924a301dd)**